# Errors for DEM terrain analysis

Tags: qgis

I am trying to do some pre-processing operations. However I use some tools and usually I cannot execute the commands. For example, I use Fill nodata from GDAL and I got the following error:
INFO GDAL execution console output

```
     gdal_fillnodata [-q] [-md max_distance] [-si smooth_iterations]

      [-o name=value] [-b band]

      srcfile [-nomask] [-mask filename] [-of format] [-co name=value]* [dstfile]
```

Moreover, I use Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu) and again I cannot run the tool having again error.

I use the last version of QGIS 3.10.1 'A Coruna', actually I downloaded the OSGeo4W Network.

I downloaded a DEM from: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/
My DEM is n39_e021_1arc_v3

What is happening and how can I fix the tools?

Comment: You are passing wrong parameters for gdal_fillnodata and therefore it prints you a message that tries to tell the right syntax. What syntax did you use?

Comment: In the input layer I put the DEM that I am using and I leave the other parameters as default

Comment: Copy the contents of GDAL/OGR console call box. You can edit the paths if they feel confidential but think if they look reasonable to you.